# Import multidimensional array from PHP to JS and iterate through it

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have an array created in PHP, which stores volume discounts for various products. I can loop through this in PHP without issue, as per the below code (this is just a small sample of the array, the real version is much bigger):

```
$product_id = 2;
    
$volumediscounts[$product_id][1]['units'] = 10;
$volumediscounts[$product_id][1]['amount'] = 90;
$volumediscounts[$product_id][2]['units'] = 3;
$volumediscounts[$product_id][2]['amount'] = 35;

foreach ($volumediscounts[$product_id] as $volOperator) {
    
    $units = $volOperator['units'];
    $amount = $volOperator['amount'];
    
    echo "Discount found: $units units @ $amount &euro;<br />";
    
}
```

My question is how can I 'import' this array to JS and iterate through it, getting the same output as above (but using console.log instead of echo)? This is required because the function to apply volume discounts is triggered by **keyup blur change** on an HTML input field. As such, I have to do this in JS.

I believe the correct way of 'importing' it is:

```
        <script>
         var items = <?php echo json_encode( $volumediscounts ) ?>;
        </script>
```

But I can't wrap my head around how to iterate through it, I've never worked with multidimensional arrays in JS before...

I hope someone can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything not working with the given code? Why not inspect what `items` contains to use it? If you want to process it using JS, is the PHP code really that relevant?

Comment: Using for loops like in basically every other language? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in that your PHP script uses the value for `$product_id` to make the loop, while you have not explicitly given this to the JavaScript script. Now, that script can of course inspect the data and see which product id(s) are present in it and have a loop for that as well.

So then it becomes:

```
<script>
const items = <?php echo json_encode( $volumediscounts ) ?>;
for (const [productId, volOperators] of Object.entries(items)) {
    console.log(`Information for product ${productId}:`);
    for (const {units, amount} of Object.values(volOperators)) {
        console.log(`  Discount found: ${units} units @ ${amount}€`);
    }
}
</script>
```